# LaTeX hyphenation problems in Spanish

Tags: hyphenation, babel, spanish

I am using this preamble on my document, edited with TeXStudio/MiKTeX
and I am getting several words not hyphenated and past the margin limits on the right side. As you can probably see, I am very new with LaTeX, so any orientation will be much appreciated

```
...old code deleted... check new example
```

Here is the result I am getting...

[image: Hyphenation problems]

here is a code snippet showing the problem

## New test code ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=2cm, top=2cm, bottom=3cm, bindingoffset=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}


\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{FCA - \thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}

\section{El Parto}

Para un buen nacimiento, el parto debe ser:

\begin{description}
\item[NATURAL] Las vacas tienen que parir solas y en ambientes higiénicos. Sobre suelos empastados si es a campo. Las fases del parto tienen que cumplirse todas, por lo que cualquier intervención más que ayudar puede ocasionar trastornos y contaminaciones a las vacas y los terneros. Sólo asistirlas en caso necesario. En el lugar estarán solamente las vacas parturientas evitando cualquier otra categoría o animales de otras especies.
\item[HIGIÉNICO] Mantener la vaca en corrales o piquetes de fácil acceso, limpios, con agua y sombra. Sin accidentes de terreno tales como zanjas, terrenos pantanosos o rocosos ya que las vacas muy pesadas pueden no levantarse si se echan en mala posición. Cuando el parto se realiza en corrales hay que evitar los suelos resbaladizos y las camas húmedas. La sombra será proporcionada por árboles de copa alta, evitando matorrales donde tengan posibilidad de esconderse o bien mediante estructuras artificiales. Las vacas deben ser vistas desde cualquier ángulo. El agua se proporcionará en bebederos. 

Para mejores resultados y un control mas fácil es conveniente  contar con una sala de maternidad, que permita una atención individual en un ambiente limpio donde disminuya la posibilidad de infecciones. Es la primer área donde el recién nacido se expone a su nuevo ambiente. La incidencia de problemas de ombligo y diarrea tienen relación directa en el área de parto y su higiene $^{(19)}$.

Las salas deben ser individuales y su cantidad depende de la distribución anual de partos. 

La alimentación se hace de noche (Ej. 8 pm) para aumentar la probabilidad de parto durante el día. (Hernández, 2012)$^{(19)}$.Las vacas permanecen en el paridero hasta 24 has después el parto para cumplir con las rutinas sanitarias y verificar la expulsión de la placenta.

\item [RAPIDO] El parto natural es rápido y se divide en tres estados consecutivos $^{(2)}$:
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code... check 2nd line right margin...]

Comment: Use the T1 encoding. The default OT1 encoding doesn't support Spanish.

Comment: just added \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} instead of \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and all my accented characters went to character heaven ... also the hyphenation problem still persist (and don't know why but the fonts look much worse than before

Comment: @Mauro You need *both* packages: `inputenc` and `fontenc` have different purposes. For the character appearance, you probably don't have the CM-Super fonts (usual for MiKTeX users). Add also `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: Manuel, added both \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} & \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} yet i still get the problems (and a much uglier font rendering??)

Comment: Which version of MikTeX is this?

Comment: MikeTeX portable, donwloaded a week ago or so and updated today

Comment: @Mauro Look at egreg's comment. And change the `A4paper` to `a4paper`. By the way, your example doesn't give the image you showed (at least for me).

Comment: @Manuel, both changes commited ... now fonts look better but still getting the same hyphenation problem ... i will repost an updated image/example

Comment: I took you last example, changed `A4paper`, added `lmodern` and added the missing `\end{description}`. Works just fine, straight right edge of the text. Using TeX Live 2013.

Comment: @daleif, check the test code i just posted ...

Comment: New code with TeX Live 2013, no problem.

Comment: Works just fine. Note that the preamble stuff after `geometry` is irrelevant for this issue.

Comment: Also tested in MiKTeX 2.9 (installed) and no problem.

Comment: @Mauro if it's still wrong, you should provide a piece of code AND the image of what that code gives you.

Comment: @Manuel, image posted with corresponding code generating it

Comment: @Nico ... still getting alignment issues ... check latest pic

Comment: No word is hyphenated. I wonder if hyphenation patterns have been loaded. See if there is an error like "No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
the language 'spanish'" (or similar) in the log file.

Comment: @JavierBezos you are right! yup.... No hyphenation patterns were loaded for(babel) the language `Spanish'(babel) I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead. so how do i load them? –

Comment: @JavierBezos i downloaded from Ctan.org spanish.dtx and spanish.ins to my babel directory on my MikTex directory ... i am still getting the same results, what is the propper way to install the lang. patterns?

Comment: It is in the miktex options. But I thought miktex enabled all languages by default. But perhaps miktex portable is different

Comment: @daleif looks like ive run into a bug, all the miktex language options are blanked out and im unable to select any ... let's download the installer and retry...

Comment: OK .... i have solved it, downloaded MikTex again (but this time the installable version) and now everything works pretty much as expected ... thanks guys

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it was solved by re-installing MiKTeX (see OP's last comment).